# .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get the following effect:

1. A user visits example.com/profile/Tom and it, in the background, makes it example.com/profile.php?username=Tom
2. Instead of making line after line of .htaccess for each URL (Figure 1), I want it to be short and work nicely, e.g. the user visits example.com/about and it uses about.php, then example.com/helloworld and it uses helloworld.php

As right now, I have to put the following for each URL I want, and instead I want 2-3 lines of .htaccess that would do the job. (If possible, more is fine, I'm not great with .htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^login/submit$ login.php?action=submit
```

Comment: is that the only rule in your .htaccess? what is Figure 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and let me know.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/])/? profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^login/submit$ login.php?action=submit [L,NC]

# /login/ will go to login.php or /contact/ will go to contact.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/? $1.php [L,NC]
```

Here's the full documentation about the `[]` flags: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, but I forgot to mention I'm working in a directory, not the root of the site. EDIT: Getting rid of the RewriteBase fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Just found an issue in this, when using a form with action="login/submit", using the form multiple times makes it stop working. E.g. if I use the form once, works fine. Press submit again, it will try /login/login/submit, and pressing it again makes it try /login/login/login/submit, and so on.

Comment: Can you try to use this in your action: `action="/login/submit"`? You probably using: `action="login/submit"`. Because the browser "thinks" the login is a folder, it just add `login` every time. Can you post your code if this does not work?

Comment: As stated before, I use subfolders in my script, and adding / before the login makes it go back to the main directory.